# Help me turn these data structures into database tables

Tags: database, data-structures

<strike>It's been a while since I've last tinkered with databases, and as usually my mind has slipped on what I need to do.  Here's me problem:</strike>

1. I have a list of entries (strings).
2. Each entry has its own name and unique ID.
3. Entries can share names, but not IDs.
4. Entries can also have properties (strings).
5. Entries can have more than one of the same property.
6. Each property for each entry can have its own value (string).

What's the best table layout for those requirements?

Okay dumb question.  Thanks anyway for the help. :P

Comment: Well, the problem for me is figuring out how to handle entries having multiple duplicate properties.  Do I create a new table for each entry or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entry table, with Name and UniqueID (PK)

Property Table, with PropertyName and ID (PK)

EntryProperty Table with EntryID (FK), PropertyID (FK), UniqueID (PK), Value.

Comment: Oh!  Duh.  Ok yeah, that solves it.  Jeez I'm spacing out. :P

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TABLE entries (
  INTEGER id NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT,
  VARCHAR(XX) name,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
)

CREATE TABLE properties (
  INTEGER id NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT,
  VARCHAR(XX) name,
  VARCHAR(XX) value,
  INTEGER entryid NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY(entryid) REFERENCES entries (id)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

> Well, the problem for me is figuring
>   out how to handle entries having
>   multiple duplicate properties. Do I
>   create a new table for each entry or
>   what?

Well, no :-)

Assuming you have an Entry and Property table, my guess is that you would need a table with the following columns:

```
id, entry_id, property_id, property_value, timestamp
```

Does that help or did I get it all wrong?